# Every element of $G/H$ has a square root iff for every $x \in G$ there is some $y \in G$ such that $xy^2 \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is a group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Every element of $G/H$ has a square root iff for every $x \in G$ there is some $y \in G$ such that $xy^2 \in H$.

Here is what I have so far:

Since every element of $G/H$ has a square root, $Hx = (Hy)^2$ for some $x, y \in G$.

$Hx = (Hy)^2$

$Hx = H(y^2)$

By theorem, we know that if $Ha = Hb$ then $ab^{-1} \in H$

But $Hx = H(y^2)$ gives me $xy^{-2} \in H$ which is not what the question is asking us to prove. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically correct, you just need to re-label your variables: Let $z=y^{-1}$, and notice that this implies $xz^2\in H$.